# trying to inner join multiple tables but always returning 0 rows

Tags: sql, database-design

I am trying to figure out why this query returns 0 rows as there is data in all 3 tables.

### Here are my tables:

Table1: Applications
Columns: ID, Name

Table2: Resources
Columns: ID, Name

Table3: ApplicationResourceBridge
Columns: ID, app_id, resource_id

### And Here is the query

```
SELECT       Resources.name
,            ApplicationResourceBridge.resource_id AS Expr3
FROM         Resources 
INNER JOIN   Applications 
ON           Resources.id = Applications.id 
INNER JOIN   ApplicationsResources 
ON           Resources.id = ApplicationResourceBridge.resource_id
```

Comment: Some of the table names in your query are not the same as you said above. For example: Your table 2 is named "Resource" but in your query you use "Resources".

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current query tries to match `Resources.id` with `Applications.id`, but they're different things.  It should match `Applications.id` with `ApplicationResources.app_id`.

It's generally clearer to have the bridge table as the middle join, so it looks like a link.  For example:

```
SELECT       Resources.name
,            ar.resource_id
FROM         Resources r
INNER JOIN   ApplicationsResources ar
ON           r.id = ar.resource_id
INNER JOIN   Applications a
ON           a.id = ar.app_id
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT r.Name AS "Resource Name" , a.Name AS "Application Name"
FROM ApplicationResourceBridge as b
INNER JOIN Resources as r ON r.ID = b. resource_id
INNER JOIN Applications as a ON a.ID = b.app_id
```

**UPDATE:**

When constructing `FROM ... JOIN ... JOIN ...` follow "the path" do not "jump over".

[image: explainmore_model_01]

Comment: @Damir:  I'd upvote this if it contained a little explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:-

```
 Applications ON Resources.id = Applications.id INNER JOIN
```

to this:-

```
 Applications ON Applications.id = ApplicationResourceBridge.app_id INNER JOIN
```

You were trying to join the Appliciation ID to the Resource ID but these have no relationship.  What you really want is to join the Application table to the Bridge table **and** the Resource table to the Bridge table.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that all three have data in them is immaterial.  The question is whether there is data in "Resources" that has the same ID as rows in BOTH "Applications" and "ApplicationResourceBridge".

Update: don't want to post this as if I thought of it but Andomar makes a good point that you seem to be attempting to link the wrong tables fields.  Thus, my answer might be right in the abstract but his might explain *why* you aren't getting field matches.